# access php file in asp.net

Tags: php, asp.net

I have asp.net application and I have php file (**adjust.php**) which have code and I want to access this file in my aspx page but I couldn't .who can do that?

**Note**: I need only access this file as I had **time server watch flash** which access this file

Comment: Please explain "want to access this file" - you can read the text of the file without a problem. Is that what you mean? No? What do you then?

Comment: you want to run PHP in ASP.NET environment (i.e. IIS) ? try FastCGI

Answer (score 0):

You can use `HttpWebRequest` and `HttpWebResponse`, to request this php file and get response string, or use `Response.Redirect("adjust.php")` to redirect to php page, you can even pass query string parameters using `Response.Redirect("adjust.php?key=value")`, other then that you can use php code inside your aspx page.